# flutter_svg not showing in release mode

Tags: flutter, svg

I spent my entire day working with this flutter_svg but I have no luck finding the problem, the SVG works only on debug mode but it does not show on release mode.

what seems to be the problem here?

package

```
    flutter_svg: any
```

Code

```
    SvgPicture.asset(
        "images/vector_intro.svg"
    ),
```

Folder

```
images/
  vector_intro.svg
```

Comment: In debug mode do you get an error in the console with something to do with Defs? Also you may want to try another image to see if the image is the problem?

Comment: it works with other SVG images, I'm using Figma and Adobe AI but it does not work. IDK what's the standard of "real" SVG

Answer (score 0):

try adding --dart-define=FLUTTER_WEB_USE_SKIA=true if you are trying this on web.
If not try upgrading your copy of flutter as the support has improved in newer versions.
Also you could try cleaning your svg with the online SVG cleaner - SVGOMG
Also  doesn't work and  also isn't supported (You could try inline style).

If none of the above doesn't work, then combine your svg into a single path.